# Customers calling about resetting their passwords, we have an automated reset tool, but still have to handle hundreds of calls per month

Tags: software-industry, software

We have an automated password reset feature that works. Since this has been implemented, we receive *more* phone calls with people requesting us to walk them through the password reset process which is automated.

Our customers literally ask us "should I click the 'I forgot my password' button?". When we say, "Yes", they then ask what they should type in for email...

Once they get the password reset link, they'll ask what they should change their password to.

Do companies with automated password resets even answer/return these calls?

How do we handle this increased workload?

We literally have to GoToMeeting with customers to see what they are doing that could make it so confusing - this is a 20-30 minute process. This is not sustainable and we are looking for other options.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that, in your application, there is a simple explanation on the use of the password reset, like the ones that use the (?) button.

Comment: I suspect the industry/service your website sits in would influence how many of these calls you're likely to get.  A company that provides online pharmaceutical orders/reminders to refill/etc would probably have a lot of older customers who "don't get modern technology" and would therefore get a lot of these calls.  A company that provides an online gaming service probably gets very few (not zero, I'm sure, but not many.)  Who would you say your customers are, and how familiar are they likely to be with the internet in general?

Comment: Why in the world are you using GoToMeeting with every single customer who forgets their password? This should be a short, 2 minute call. "Oh, you forgot your password? Click the 'I forgot my password' button. ... yep, enter the email address you want the email sent to. .. Uh. Huh. ... You'll receive an email to that address with a link to reset your password. Click the link and enter your new password and you'll be all set. Anything else I can help you with today? No. Ok. Thanks for calling COMPANY"

Comment: @ChrisG That's half my job. We wouldn't be able to handle the kind of volume we do if we're going to a remote session for even half of our calls. Remote sessions should be last resort only.

Comment: @Thebluefish absolutely. I ran a SaaS solution's Support/Services team for several years. I used something like GoToMeeting maybe a half dozen times when things went totally nuts. I didn't even pull up their account for at least 1/3 of the calls. "You're trying to X? Click here, click here, click here, check that box, generate the report. Is that what you were looking for? ... Great! ... No problem. Thanks for calling."

Comment: Also, Stack Exchange has a https://ux.stackexchange.com/ which may be the right venue for getting feedback or guidance for dealing with the password reset problem in general.

Comment: Do you have a bit of scope with your user base?  What % is this "hundreds"?  What are the demographics?  What is this login used for?

Comment: Why the reset password process asks for email ? So, may I ask to reset another customers password and give my own email ? weird.

Comment: "We have an automated password reset feature that works." - Works does not mean usable (also called user-friendly or good UX). Try to determine what is confusing about it and then fix those problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem you're having _at work_, not one with navigating the workplace.

Comment: @MaskedMan thanks for the snarky comment! always appreciate the negativity! Why would it be labeled that? Even stack overflows link is "forgot?"! Are you questioning whether stack exchange has done usability testing? Thanks for trying to address the issue in a negative way, instead of say, "have you thought about the link text?".

Comment: Create YouTube video, add FAQ article which explains the process in words and provides screenshots and links to the YouTube video, refer to people to this article and stop providing remote support assistance for this issue.

Answer (score 11):

> Do companies with automated password resets even answer/return these
>   calls?

only the ones that want to make their customers happy.

> How do we handle this increased workload?

Write a better script for the folks taking these calls to use to help customers through resetting their passwords.

If you actually have to see what they are doing, then your process is too difficult (for you and likely for your customers). You may need to spend some time simplifying it. Perhaps a written How To document with pictures that you could send to customers would speed things up.

Alternatively, outsource these calls to a facility with more capacity or bring on some temp workers until the requests die down.

You call this "an automated password reset feature that works". While it might work functionally, your customers seem to be hinting that it *doesn't work for them*. Somewhere along the line you seem to have an ease-of-use issue.

You might be well served to find out why it doesn't meet their needs, so you can improve the feature next time. I'm also guessing that you didn't perform any Beta testing of this new feature to see how your customers actually handle it in the wild. That might be something you want to consider for the next time around. A few dollars invested in professional testing might have prevented this situation.

Comment: There’s something in this. OP, I use a simple rule as part of my evaluation of solutions we implement: if a few people have problems with a feature, it’s probably down to them. If *lots* of people struggle with a feature, it’s an issue with that feature. So apparently, this feature causes a lot of problems... see where I’m going with this?

Comment: There are 4 people who work here. There is no call center. The developers are doing the support.

Comment: Correct. There are 4 of us. It has been so time consuming that I think outsourcing may be the only option

Comment: @JoeStrazzere we have gone through so much testing. and our testing _involved_ our customers that were having a problem. We literally had them in on discussions about how to present the reset issues. The interface is so incredibly simple it is maddening. The most common call we get is "Should I click the I forgot my password" link? Thx for the advice.

Comment: @john_h Outsource that stuff to a help desk service if you can.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere *Our customers literally ask us "should I click the 'I forgot my password' button?". When we say, "Yes", they then ask what they should type in for email...* Seems like they have what pretty much every site have to handle loss of password. To me thid kind of client just seems very not used too computer/internet usage. If it is that, forming the client for every functionnality added is probably better.

Comment: It doesn’t matter how easy you think the password reset feature is. It doesn’t matter how easy it *actually* is. If lots of customers are struggling then it isn’t easy enough for your customer base, simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

If adding the automated tool has ***increased*** the need for hand-holding, then the customer interface of the automated tool is not user friendly and is poorly designed.

You, in customer service, have to be the data collection point.  You can identify and quantify the problem ("The tool is confusing the customers, they call to get help on how to use the automated tool"), and you can record, very easily, what they are struggling with and their feedback on why it isn't clear to them.  Once you've recorded the actual data on the problem, those in charge of design can make changes that will directly impact the problem.

Your continued data collection can validate that their solutions have improved, made worse, or had no impact on the problems.

The tool is supposed to reduce the amount of interaction you have to do on this specific issue, it is clearly having the opposite effect.  Instead of my just advising you on how to handle the callers, you can be crucial in focusing in on and addressing the problem.

Taking this approach will turn heads. You are looking at a personal work issue from a larger, strategic perspective, you are finding ways to identify specific problems in a way that others can see it is an actual problem, and in a way that they can address the problems.  All of that should lead to better service for the customers and reduce non-value-added service time, helping your company's bottom line.

Holding seminars that teach the customers to figure out the interface, instead of changing the interface itself is, you are correct, a band-aid solution that will never end, unless you don't have future customers.

Answer (score 2):

I worked at a help desk in a place where they got an automatic password reset software tool.  Unfortunately the top management wasn't behind the change so the help desk was left to manage this new process.  There was no training and no communication that the software was being rolled out for end users, it was just rolled out.

However I came up with a step-by-stop job aid in MS Word that I converted into a pdf file and that my supervisor and department manager approved of.  Whenever we got a call for help with using the password reset software, we emailed the directions to that person and told them to follow the basic directions.  We encouraged the other person on the end of the phone to print out the directions and share it with others, in the hopes that they would learn how to do this themselves.

For the most part it reduced calls to the help desk for that type of call.